# python: subprocess.Popen() behaviour

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am trying to use rsync with python. I have read that the preferred way to passing arguments to Popen is using an array.

The code I tried:

```
p = Popen(["rsync",
        "\"{source}\"".format(source=latestPath),
        "\"{user}@{host}:{dir}\"".format(user=user, host=host, dir=dir)],
        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

The result is rsync asking for password, even though I have set up SSH keys to do the authentication.

I think this is a problem with the environment the new process gets executed in. What I tried next is:

```
p = Popen(["rsync", 
   "\"{source}\"".format(source=latestPath),
   "\"{user}@{host}:{dir}\"".format(user=user, host=host, dir=dir)],
   stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

This results in rsync printing the "correct usage", so the arguments are passed incorrectly to rsync. I am not sure if this is even supposed to work(passing an array with shell=True)

If I remove the array altogether like this:

```
p = Popen("rsync \"{source}\" \"{user}@{host}:{dir}\"".format(
        source=latestPath, user=user, host=host, dir=dir),
      stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

The program works fine. It really doesn't matter for the sake of this script, but I'd like to know what's the difference? Why don't the other two(mainly the first one) work?

Is it just that the shell environment is required, and the second one is incorrect?

EDIT: Contents of the variables

```
latestPath='/home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/MC 4thworld/workspace/target/FourthWorld-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
user='mc'
host='192.168.0.32'
dir='/mc/test/plugins/'
```

Comment: If you're using the list syntax for commands, I don't think you need the extra quotes `\"`.  So you could just:
`Popen([
    'rsync', 
    latestPath, 
    '{user}@{host}:{dir}'.format(user=user, host=host, dir=dir)
])

Comment: @hwjp How well does it handle spaces in the paths, if the quotes are not there?

Comment: The second one is also correct. subprocess will accept an array even when using `shell=True`. In fact on my system the command works (with dummy values for `source`, `user`, `host` and `dir`. What are the contents of your variables?

Comment: spaces should be fine. try it.

Comment: @HansThen I added example contents of the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know what's the difference?

When `shell=True`, the entire command is passed to the shell. The quotes are there so the shell can correctly pick the command apart again. In particular, passing

`foo "bar baz"`

to the shell causes it to parse the command as (Python syntax) `['foo', 'bar baz']` so that it can execute the `foo` command with the argument `bar baz`.

By contrast, when `shell=False`, Python will pass the arguments in the list to the program immediately. For example, try the following `subprocess` commands:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["echo", '"Hello!"'])
"Hello!"
0
>>> subprocess.call('echo "Hello!"', shell=True)
Hello!
0
```

and note that in the first, the quotes are echoed back at you by the `echo` program, while in the second case, the shell has stripped them off prior to executing `echo`.

In your specific case, `rsync` gets the quotes but doesn't know how it's supposed to handle them; it's not itself a shell, after all.

Comment: I wondered why it was "asking password" for "mc@... I thought there was just something wrong with the printing :-)

Comment: @varesa: please post the *exact* string of list you're passing to `Popen`.

Comment: What do you mean by string of list?

Comment: @varesa: string *or* list, sorry.

Comment: Now there are both, the "joined" string and the array as I think it is

Comment: @varesa: I can't explain this. You should be getting a different error message.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be to do with the `cwd` or `env` parameters?  Maybe in the first syntax, it can't find the SSH keys...

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, it might be easier for you to use [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh) instead of subprocess:

```
import sh
sh.rsync(latestPath, user+"@"+host+":"+dir)
```

Comment: I have got the script to work now, so I don't think I'll touch it too much. I'll keep that in mind the next time I have to do something similar